# How to dispose a jframe after 5secs and open a next jframe

Tags: java, eclipse

I want my jframe( 1 label and 1 image in a single panel) to be shown for 5 secs and then dispose. After that next jframe automatically appears

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried? Also, have you tried using timers?

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There is a section on `How to Use Swing Timers`.